# Dask client causing memory expection?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I´ve been migrating some of my codes from pandas do dask. Many of them are already working. Studing a little bit more about dask, I´ve faced it "Client()" feature for monitoring usage. Nice function! But it does break my code!

Dask without client

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

def carregar ():
    df = dd.read_parquet(path=f'{pastafonte}\\Unificado',  parse_dates=['data'])
    df['parceiro'] = df.parceiro.cat.add_categories('Not_available').fillna('Not_available') 
    df['mci'] = df['mci'].fillna(0)
    df['sku'] = df['sku'].fillna(df['marca'].astype(str))
    df['cod_transacao'] = df['cod_transacao'].fillna('Not_available')
    return df
dftotal = carregar()
gerado = dftotal.loc[(dftotal.parceiro != 'Amazon') | ((dftotal.parceiro == 'Amazon') & (dftotal.status == 'indefinido'))] 

df = dftotal.groupby(['produto','parceiro', 'marca',dftotal.data.dt.to_period("M"), 'status'], dropna=False, observed=True).aggregate({'gmv': 'sum', 'receita': 'sum', 'cashback': 'sum'}).reset_index()

dfafiliados = dftotal.loc[(dftotal.produto == 'Afiliados')]
dfafiliados = dfafiliados.groupby(['produto','parceiro', 'marca',dfafiliados.data.dt.to_period("M"), 'status'], dropna=False, observed=True)['cod_transacao'].nunique().reset_index()
dfafiliados = dfafiliados.rename(columns={ 'cod_transacao' : 'qtde_vendas'})
dfafiliados = dfafiliados.loc[dfafiliados.qtde_vendas != 0] #Para substituir o "observed=True" que não está funcionando

dfoutros = dftotal.loc[(dftotal.produto != 'Afiliados')]
dfoutros.cod_transacao = dfoutros.cod_transacao.fillna('Não disponível')
dfoutros = dfoutros.groupby(['produto','parceiro', 'marca',dfoutros.data.dt.to_period("M"), 'status'], dropna=False, observed=True).aggregate({'cod_transacao' :'count'}).reset_index()
dfoutros = dfoutros.rename(columns={ 'cod_transacao' : 'qtde_vendas'})

dfnunique = dd.concat([dfafiliados,dfoutros], axis=0)#, ignore_order = True

df = df.merge(dfnunique,how='left', on=['produto','parceiro', 'marca','data', 'status'])

df['data'] = df['data'].astype({'data' : 'datetime64[ns]'}) # type: ignore
df = df[['produto','parceiro','marca','data','status','qtde_vendas','gmv','receita','cashback']]
df = df.compute()
df = df.sort_values( by = ['produto','parceiro', 'marca','data','status'])
```

And it all runs ok in about 30 seconds.

But if it run the same code, excepct for adding the client, it runs out of memory

```
Client = Client()
Client

2023-10-24 23:22:14,645 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:52395 (pid=17668) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-24 23:22:15,090 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-24 23:22:15,363 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:52401 (pid=4388) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-24 23:22:15,584 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-24 23:22:19,561 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:52402 (pid=26016) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-24 23:22:19,778 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-10-24 23:22:21,731 - distributed.nanny.memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:52398 (pid=18488) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2023-10-24 23:22:22,074 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

I´ve tried to create a sample dataframe to reproduce such error but I couldnt (I dont know I would need to test using a much larger sample), but even using a smaller dataframe, I can see a warning using client that does not happen using without client.

Without client

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
import numpy as np

num_variables = 1_000_000
rng = np.random.default_rng()

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' :  np.random.randint(1,99999,num_variables),
    'date' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2021,1,1),datetime(2022,12,31))) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'product' : [np.random.choice(['giftcards', 'afiliates']) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'brand' : [np.random.choice(['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_4', 'brand_6', np.nan]) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'gmv' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100,
    'revenue' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100})

data = data.astype({'product': 'category', 'brand':'category'})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=5)

df = ddf.groupby([ddf.date.dt.to_period('M'), 'product','brand'], dropna=False, observed=True).aggregate({'id' : 'count'}).reset_index()
df = df.compute()
```

Runs in 0.0 seconds!

Now with client

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
import numpy as np

Client = Client()
Client

num_variables = 1_000_000
rng = np.random.default_rng()

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' :  np.random.randint(1,99999,num_variables),
    'date' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2021,1,1),datetime(2022,12,31))) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'product' : [np.random.choice(['giftcards', 'afiliates']) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'brand' : [np.random.choice(['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_4', 'brand_6', np.nan]) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'gmv' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100,
    'revenue' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100})

data = data.astype({'product': 'category', 'brand':'category'})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=5)

df = ddf.groupby([ddf.date.dt.to_period('M'), 'product','brand'], dropna=False, observed=True).aggregate({'id' : 'count'}).reset_index()
df = df.compute()

UserWarning: Sending large graph of size 28.62 MiB.
This may cause some slowdown.
Consider scattering data ahead of time and using futures.
  warnings.warn(
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the last snippet, `data` is a large dataframe generated locally, which is sent to `dask.dataframe` (this causes the `UserWarning`)... However, the error is not clear... Can you show the error message and traceback?

Comment: When creating a Client, you actually create a local distributed cluster that will split the available memory between processes. Default Dask Dataframe behavior is to use only thread. If you are on a recent computer, creating a Client will probably create 4 or 8 workers, so each of those workers will only have a quarter or an eight of your total memory. Depending on your workflow, this can make a difference. You can try with cluster = LocalCluster(nworkers=1, nthreads=8) client = Client(cluster).

Comment: But shouldn't dask on create several workers to calculate The memory available to each one?